# Faye: Can't send GET messages in browser even though socket is open, working and responding with data via CURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, thin, faye

So my websocket is opening properly to faye, I'm using the nginx_tcp_proxy module.  When I run a curl it looks good:

```
$ curl http://now.2u.fm:9200/faye\?message\=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fhandshake%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22supportedConnectionTypes%22%3A%5B%22callback-polling%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D\&jsonp\=__jsonp6__
__jsonp6__([{"id":"1","channel":"/meta/handshake","successful":true,"version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","cross-origin-long-polling","callback-polling","websocket","eventsource","in-process"],"clientId":"jls0srprht51xb368yrojft3h4drgu0","advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}]);#
```

And curl with the -I flag

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Connection: close
```

But I'm getting failed GET requests when my website tries to hit this as GET (no error code):

[image]

edit: I noticed it says "switching protocols" just now!

[image]

Same as when I try and hit [the url](http://now.2u.fm:9200/faye%5C?message%5C=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fhandshake%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22supportedConnectionTypes%22%3A%5B%22callback-polling%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%5C&jsonp%5C=__jsonp6__) directly in my browser.

My gut says, "hey, thats because you have a tcp connection open not an http one!", but then is private_pub using GET?  But for all I know a GET request is just fine over TCP and I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was that Faye needs to be able to open a socket and use http.  Because private_pub assumes you do both on the same domain/port this was impossible using the tcp module without having to modify private_pub and the faye extension it was loading to use the right ports.

In the end I used HAProxy instead as it was much simpler to set up and required no modification of private pub.

Comment: Can you link to a good place to learn how to add HAProxy to a typical nginx/unicorn/rails setup?